# Visual studio hang during go to definition and not searching any thing?

Tags: .net

While able to Go to defintion(F12),i am not able to search any reference in solution.
Please help me sort this

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Its worked for me.

Delete the contents from the following folders

C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation

C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio

C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VSCommon

- notice AppData is Hidden so go to Folder options and check Show hidden files.